# Unity Facebook SDK - Strange FB.Login() Behavior in iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, unity-game-engine, facebook-login

I'm working on connecting an app to Facebook using the Facebook SDK for Unity.  The process seems to be working fine except sometimes if a new user tries to use Facebook to login the FB.Login() doesn't ask them for permission to use their birthday and email. 
Im using this call for the login:

FB.Login("email, user_birthday", AuthCallback);

and in the Facebook app dashboard, under permissions I added email and user birthday.

What seems to be happening is the first time the user goes to use the Facebook connect and hasn't ok'd the permissions on the login yet when they sign in a dialog pops up in the Facebook webview as them to authorize my app for "friends list and public profile" they hit ok and then my login process fails because I need access to the birthday and email.  If they hit my login button again then the FB.Login() function runs again bringing up a second dialog asking for permission to use email and birthday, after they ok this my own login works fine.  The other option is to hit the home button on the device reopen the app hit the  Facebook connect button again and this time the authorization dialog has all four options "public profile, friends list, email, and birthday"

I followed the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/ for the connect process so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Any insight into this would be helpful.  Just unsure of where to continue looking I have exhausted most of my debugging avenues but I'm new to the Facebook scene, so it's possible i missed something.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT** I'm using Facebook SDK version 4.2.1 and Unity 4.2.0f4

Comment: If I understand you correctly this bug is only happening on the first login for a new user, correct?  How are you switching users?  We cache access tokens on a per app basis and try to use them to login when FB.init is called.  If you have the access token for one user, but have switched users on the facebook app, this could lead to some weird behavior like you're seeing.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. It also seems like publish_actions allows you to post to the timeline with certain devices while publish_stream is needed for others. I've experienced many inconsistencies with the Facebook SDK for Unity.